# What is hiding the Left Navigation Bar on this Seattle hub site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Version : Office 365 (SharePoint 2016? 2019?)

I didn't create those sites.

The structure is as follows :

- Site collection A = hub site
- Site collection B = site collection that's part of A's hub.

I observe that B has a Seattle layout. Most other look options are disabled because it's part of a hub site so SharePoint doesn't let you change them. **The left side bar is VISIBLE.**

I observe that A (he hub) has a Seattle layout too. When I go to "Change the look" --> "Navigation" I observe that "Display the navigation" is set to "Show". And yet **the left side bar is NOT VISIBLE.**

**Question: What can cause the side bar not to be visible on site A? I can't explain it.**
I don't believe the users had enough knowledge to implement any fancy page layout or CSS. Itäs got to be basic SharePoint.

*(While writing this I can think of one possible scenario : This specific page of site A is the home page. It might have a layout that doesn't have the side bar?)*

*EDIT: The page I was looking at on A is home.aspx so it might indeed have a special layout. I don't remember if that's how it's supposed to be.*

*EDIT 2: No, I've check a List page from site A and the Left Nav Bar is hidden there just like on home.aspx, whereas a List page of B does show the Left Nav Bar. What causes the difference?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communication sites do not have a Quick Launch where as Team sites do have a Quick Launch.

You can see what type of template was used from the SharePoint Admin Center in 'Active Sites'.

SharePoint Online has no version, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have access to the SharePoint Admin Center as I'm only Site collection administrator, not power user. But I'm guessing that's the hidden reason. Shot in the foot by some SharePoint black magic once again!